# Issue With Struts2 URL

Tags: tomcat, servlets, url-rewriting, struts2

If I append # followed by / (#/) to the URL(Lets say the URL is http://hostname:portnumber/ActionName.do), It is rewriting the browser URL with **hostname:portnumber** but the page doesn't get redirected to this(**hostname:portnumber**) URL. Any idea what may be causing this strange behaviour?  I'm using struts2 framework and Tomcat version 8.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: It depends how did you use the url.